# Printing from a dictionary single values

Tags: json, swift, struct, jsondecoder

Currently trying to get to print all strTeam from the teams:[Team] dictionary.
Any guidance here will be appreciated.

If you see any other mistakes please let me know. Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("testing")
        
        let url = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_teams.php?l=English_Premier_League"
        getData(from: url)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func getData(from url:String){
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            
            // Received the data
            var result: Response?
            
            do{
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            }
            catch{
                print("failed to connect \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            
            print(json.teams)
            // WOULD LIKE TO ONLY PRINT all teams.strTeam HERE
            
            
        })
        task.resume()
    }

}

struct Response: Codable {
    let teams: [Teams]
}

struct Teams: Codable{
    let strTeam : String
    let strStadium : String
}
```

I have attempted json.teams.strTeam but get an error.

I know json.teams[i].strTeam gives me a single value but I would like all strTeam values printed.

This may be super easy but I just started learning Swift.

Comment: Did either answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the `strTeam` values by doing this:

```
print(json.teams.map(\.strTeam))
```

The `map` function takes an array and transforms it into a new array. In this case, we're taking the original array of `Teams` and transforms it into an array of just the `strTeam` property of each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for name in json.teams {
       print("WOULD LIKE TO ONLY PRINT all teams.strTeam HERE", name.strStadium)
   }
```

[image]